# Число вида - 0.0001 отображается на странице как 0

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Использую `<fmt:formatNumber value="${nckoopsql.cp}" type="number"/>` для того чтобы убрать незначащие нули у числа, но есть проблема, число вида - 0.0001 отображается на странице как 0, пришлось использовать вот такую конструкцию `replaceAll("\\.(.*?)0+$", ".$1").replaceAll("\\.$", "")`, собственно вопрос, можно ли вывести это число средствами `jstl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может [это](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm) то что вы искали?

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "fmt" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>JSTL fmt:formatNumber Tag</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h3>Number Format:</h3>
      <c:set var = "balance" value = "120000.2309" />

      <p>Formatted Number (1): <fmt:formatNumber value = "${balance}" 
         type = "currency"/></p>

      <p>Formatted Number (2): <fmt:formatNumber type = "number" 
         maxIntegerDigits = "3" value = "${balance}" /></p>

      <p>Formatted Number (3): <fmt:formatNumber type = "number" 
         maxFractionDigits = "3" value = "${balance}" /></p>

      <p>Formatted Number (4): <fmt:formatNumber type = "number" 
         groupingUsed = "false" value = "${balance}" /></p>

      <p>Formatted Number (5): <fmt:formatNumber type = "percent" 
         maxIntegerDigits="3" value = "${balance}" /></p>

      <p>Formatted Number (6): <fmt:formatNumber type = "percent" 
         minFractionDigits = "10" value = "${balance}" /></p>

      <p>Formatted Number (7): <fmt:formatNumber type = "percent" 
         maxIntegerDigits = "3" value = "${balance}" /></p>

      <p>Formatted Number (8): <fmt:formatNumber type = "number" 
         pattern = "###.###E0" value = "${balance}" /></p>

      <p>Currency in USA :
         <fmt:setLocale value = "en_US"/>
         <fmt:formatNumber value = "${balance}" type = "currency"/>
      </p>

   </body>
</html>
```

ну и дальше результат:

```
Number Format:

Formatted Number (1): £120,000.23

Formatted Number (2): 000.231

Formatted Number (3): 120,000.231

Formatted Number (4): 120000.231

Formatted Number (5): 023%

Formatted Number (6): 12,000,023.0900000000%

Formatted Number (7): 023%

Formatted Number (8): 120E3

Currency in USA : $120,000.23
```